# Accessing properties of elements in a collection to create new collections

Tags: c#, collections

Is there any way to define a table as a collection of rows, and automatically populate properties (columns) on the table according to the properties of the rows?

For example:

```
public class Foobar {
    public int TheNumber;
    public string TheString;
}

public class SomeFoobars : List<Foobar> {
    public List<int> TheNumber { 
        get { return Select(foo => foo.TheNumber); }
        set { for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++) { this[i].TheNumber = value[i]; } 
    }
    public List<int> TheString { 
        get { return Select(foo => foo.TheString ); }
        set { for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++) { this[i].TheString = value[i]; } 
    }
}

// So I can now do things like:
SomeFoobars myFoobars = ReturnsListOfFoobar();
MethodThatTakesListOfInt( myFoobars.TheNumbers );
myFoobars.TheString = SomeMethodThatReturnsListOfString();
```

Creating the collection class implementation isn't so bad if you only have to do it once, but I would like to have this functionality for any type of row and not have to write the collection properties over and over. These property methods are essentially identical, other than the reference to the specific property on the contained class (i.e. `TheNumber` or `TheString` in the example above).

Is there any way to accomplish this? Perhaps using reflection?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go back and revise your design. As you may realize now, it is causing a lot of trouble to you.

With that being said if you still decide to keep the current kits, you can remove the properties on `SomeFoobars` and still do the same in this way :

```
MethodThatTakesListOfInt(
    myFoobars
        .Select(f => f.TheNumber)
        .ToList());

SomeMethodThatReturnsListOfString()
    .Select((s,i) => new { Index = i, String = s })
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x => myFoobars[x.Index].TheString = x.String);
```